# Firebase server key and sender id exposed to public

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it save to expose firebase cloud messaging server key (legacy) and sender id in client js code ? If an attacker gain access to those keys what damage can attacker do ?

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the key already implies, the FCM server key should only be used on a server (or an otherwise trusted environment, such as Cloud Functions). Anyone who has this key can send messages to all users of your app.